# How can I get child "payload" On Coap

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, client-server, payload, coap

[image: Coap Server ScreenShot]

On the left side,I have LightRGB and ı can get the LightRGB payload with Client get request.I have ChangeColor as LightRGB child unfortunately  but I can't get the ChangeColor payload.Payload is a xml output as you can see on the right side of the photo

How Can I get the ChangeColor payload with Python Client request.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the `ChangeColor` resource as a child resource of `LightRGB`;
In CoAP, a child resource cannot access the parent Request handlers (ex: GET) unless you allow it. 
I actually have low experience in **CoAPthon** as I have only worked with *CoAP java implementation* ([californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium)).
In **californium** there is a way you can use the GET handler of a parent resource also in the child resource.

```
public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) //This is the child resouce GET handler
{
     this.getParent().handleRequest(exchange); //This line calls the original parent resource request handler.
}
```

Hope you can find a similar solution to address this matter with Python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it was very helpful.

Comment: glad that it did :)